# Control firefox tabs

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I'm working on a firefox extension, until now I was working with XUL [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/browser), to control the user navigation across web sites and save the visited pages, but the browser is limited, I tried a simple google search, when I click on some result, it won't be displayed in the browser.

One idea is to move the xul application to Dialog and control the actual firefox tabs.
But I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to "control firefox tabs" in Firefox's own `TabBrowser`, or are you creating an additional window and using a `Browser` element to render some remote content? If the latter, why?

Comment: I'm trying the first option, I want to log websites visited in firefox Tabs.

Comment: Ok, putting together an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(per your comment....)

To create an addon that logs TAB 'load' events, create a bootstrapped (restartless) addon:

- bootstrap.js (The JavaScript file containing your 'privileged' code)
- install.rdf (an XML file describing your addon to Firefrox)

To build the addon, simply place both files inside the top-level (no folders!) of a ZIP file with the file extension `.xpi`. To install the addon, navigate to `about:addons` then from the tools menu, click `Install from file`, find your XPI, open it, then after a short delay choose `Install`.

---

In `install.rdf` put something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>youraddonname@yourdomain</em:id>
        <em:type>2</em:type>
        <em:name>Name of your addon</em:name>
        <em:version>1.0</em:version>
        <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
        <em:description>Describe your addon.</em:description>
        <em:creator>Your name</em:creator>

        <!-- Firefox Desktop -->
        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>4.0.*</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>29.0.*</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>
    </Description>
</RDF>
```

---

You need to implement two mandatory JavaScript functions in the `bootstrap.js`:

- `startup()` - called when you install the addon, and when your browser starts up.
- `shutdown()` - called when you uninstall the addon, and when your browser shuts down.

You should call all of the 'privileged' code from `startup()`. For hygiene, you can (and probably should) also implement `install()` and `uninstall()` functions.

Start by implementing the following code in `bootstrap.js`:

```
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
let consoleService = Cc["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"]
                        .getService(Ci.nsIConsoleService);
let wm             = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                        .getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);

function LOG(msg) {
  consoleService.logStringMessage("EXTENSION: "+msg);    
}

function startup() {
  try {
    LOG("starting up...");
    let windows = wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
    while (windows.hasMoreElements()) {
      let chromeWindow = windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
      WindowListener.setupBrowserUI(chromeWindow);
    }
    wm.addListener(WindowListener);
    LOG("done startup.");
  } catch (e) {
    LOG("error starting up: "+e);
  }
}

function shutdown() {
  try {
    LOG("shutting down...");
    let windows = wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
    while (windows.hasMoreElements()) {
      let chromeWindow = windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
      WindowListener.tearDownBrowserUI(chromeWindow);
    }
    wm.addListener(WindowListener);
    LOG("done shutdown.");
  } catch (e) {
    LOG("error shutting down: "+e);
  }
}
```

Basically, that calls `WindowListener.setupBrowserUI()` for each current & future window of your web-browser. `WindowListener` is defined as follows:

```
var WindowListener = {
  setupBrowserUI: function(chromeWindow) {
    chromeWindow.gBrowser.addEventListener('load', my_load_handler, true);
  },
  tearDownBrowserUI: function(chromeWindow) {
    chromeWindow.gBrowser.removeEventListener('load', my_load_handler, true);
  },
  onOpenWindow: function(xulWindow) {
    let chromeWindow = xulWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                         .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
    chromeWindow.addEventListener("load", function listener() {
      chromeWindow.removeEventListener("load", listener, false);
      var domDocument = chromeWindow.document.documentElement;
      var windowType = domDocument.getAttribute("windowtype");
      if (windowType == "navigator:browser")
        WindowListener.setupBrowserUI(chromeWindow);
    }, false);
  },
  onCloseWindow: function(chromeWindow) { },
  onWindowTitleChange: function(chromeWindow, newTitle) { }
};
```

That sets up an event listener for the `OpenWindow` event, and in turn installs an event listener for `load` events in the `TabBrowser` of each ChromeWindow. The `load` event handler is defined as:

```
var my_load_handler = function (evt) {
  try {
    var browserEnumerator = wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
    while (browserEnumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
      var browserWin = browserEnumerator.getNext();
      var tabbrowser = browserWin.gBrowser;
      var numTabs = tabbrowser.browsers.length;
      for (var index = 0; index < numTabs; index++) {
        var currentBrowser = tabbrowser.getBrowserAtIndex(index);
        var domWindow = currentBrowser.contentWindow.wrappedJSObject;
        if (!domWindow.hasOwnProperty('__logged_this_window__')) {
          LOG("TAB loaded:");
          LOG("   URL: "+domWindow.location.href);
          LOG("   TITLE: "+domWindow.title)
          domWindow.__logged_this_window__ = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    LOG(e);
  }
}
```

So basically, if there's a `load` event on any of the `TabBrowser` elements in Firefox, that function will run. It'll enumerate all of the Firefox windows, and all of those windows' tabs (`Browser` elements).  The trick is that when a page reloads all the custom properties on a "content" `DomWindow` are lost, so we check to see if a custom property is present. If not, then we log details of the TAB's content page.

Comment: There are more 'direct' ways than enumerating all windows & TABs. (e.g: using nsIProgressListener interface) but this way is very easy to understand.